# Source field in not been shown while using the following query

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using the following script fields query. It is getting me the score I wanted to have , but not the _source field. How can I solve the problem?. Here is the query Iam running.

```
{
    "terms": {
      "closing": ["wed"
      ]
    }
  }
  "script_fields": {
    "index": {
      "script": "doc['collection'].value / doc['people'].value"
    }    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is when using script_fields, the response will not include "_source" by default. You need to specify it explicitly in the query. Modify your query like below and see if you are getting the results as expected

```
{
    "terms": {
      "closing": ["wed"
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "my_score": {
      "script": "doc['collection'].value / doc['people'].value"
    }
  }
}
```